# Get title of page with link

Tags: javascript, jquery, page-title

I have a link in a texbox. When I click a button I want to take the title of the page of the link. How can do it with javascript or jQuery?

Comment: nothing actually. I want to learn if it's possible or not.

Comment: The title of the page that the link references, or the title of the page containing the link?  (One is easy, the other is not.)

Comment: I need the remote page's title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this post can give you a start

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/get-external-page-and-fetch-title-googled-a-lot-didn-t-find-any-solution

Answer (score 0):

If the page is in the same domain, I'd say use an ajax request and get the title from the returned DOM object.

If it's a different domain, I'd say set a hidden IFrame to the location and when it's loaded get the title using something like:

```
document.getElementById('MyIframe').document.title
```

Comment: I can't because not in the same domain and page doesn't allowed to loan in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost always done by backend script/crawler. It fetches webpage for You on server-side and returns parsed data by AJAX

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="googleLink">Google</a>
<span id="titleGoesHere"></span>
```

--

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#googleLink').click(function(){
        $.get(this.prop('href'), function(data) {
            var $temp = $('<div id="tempData" />');
            $temp.append(data);
            var title = $('title', $temp);
            $('#titleGoesHere').html(title.val());
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from within scripts. And because we are using client-side Javascript on the front end for web scraping, CORS errors can occur.
>
> ...
>
> Staying firmly within our front end script, we can use cross-domain tools such as Any Origin, Whatever Origin, All Origins, crossorigin and probably a lot more. I have found that you often need to test a few of these to find the one that will work on the site you are trying to scrape.

From [this post](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/client-side-web-scraping-with-javascript-using-jquery-and-regex-5b57a271cb86), I wrote this **working and self-contained** fiddle:

```js
function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}

const url = "https://www.facebook.com/"

$.getJSON('https://allorigins.me/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '&callback=?', function(data){
    const content = replaceAll(data.contents, "<script", "<meta");
    $("#content").append(content);
    const d = $("#content");
    $('#title').text(d.find('title').text());
  $('#description').text(d.find('meta[name=description]').attr("content") || "None");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content" style="display: none;">
</div>

<h3 id="title">Waiting...</h3>

<br/>

<p id="description">Waiting...</p>
```

---

A few comments:

- Use a cross-domain tool through https
- Don't forget to `encodeURIComponent` your url
- I replaced `script` tags with `meta` tags so that none of those are executed when appended to the DOM (replace function from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript))
- To be used, parsed jQuery must be added to the dom (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808770/parsing-of-html-string-using-jquery))