# How to get an element and all attributes as a string in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a native/jQuery method to return an elements opening tag with all its attributes and their values as a string.

It should look something like this.

HTML:

```
<body id="mybody" class="someclass">

</body>
```

Non-existing jQuery function:

```
$("body").tagAsString(); //returns <body id="mybody" class="someclass">
```

or non-existing native function:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].tagToString();
```

I can get all attributes of an element with their values, but I need the exact string as it is just in the HTML. 
Looking for the length of the whole opening tag.

Comment: You likely won't be able to get it exactly as it is in the html due to how the browser interprets html, however you can get the browsers' interpretation of it using .outerHTML on the dom node.

Comment: Is there a reason you need this? It's an odd requirement, which sounds like a bad solution to a different problem.

Comment: I'm replacing the <body> content with the <body> content from another page retrieved by ajax, but I don't always have control over the other page. I'm currently getting all content in the retrieved body by using data.substring(data.indexOf("<body>") + 6, data.indexOf("</body>"). if the retrieved data has more then 6 characters in the body tag, my script will fail, so I need the length

Comment: Have you tried something like `$(data).find('body')` and working with that?

Comment: @Milfert definitely an XY problem then - just do `$(document.body).empty().append($(data).children())`

Comment: Thought I had the right way of approaching so I asked the question like this. Appears I didn't and need another approach. Cheers for the help so far!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that, once the HTML has been parsed, the browser doesn't care about it any more. The DOM structure that the browser has interpreted is all that matters. The HTML is gone. Kaput. Finished. Ignored.

[image: How the browser thinks of the HTML after parsing it.]

The browser does not keep the "original HTML" in any way. In fact, the browser doesn't really like HTML. It's not how it thinks, and converting things to HTML can be a bit tricky.

All you can get is a representation of how the browser currently has the element. This may well not be the same as the HTML. For instance, any attributes that have been changed in the DOM will appear differently to the original HTML.

The process might look like this:

```
var html = $(document.body)
    .clone() // get a copy of the element to work on
    .empty() // empty it
    .appendTo('<div/>').parent().html(); // equivalent to outerHTML
```

This gives a result like:

```
'<body class="question-page"></body>'
```

You could then remove everything from the final `<`:

```
html = html.substr(0,html.lastIndexOf('<'));
```

Which gives:

```
'<body class="question-page">'
```

Comment: After all the testing and researching I would say this actually is the real answer to my **original** question. Alnitak showed me that, in fact, I asked the wrong question. I'm marking this as the accepted answer, but note that your code appends $(document.body) into a div, while the <body> is not a valid child of a <div>, so the actual <body> element does not get appended into the <div>, it's contents does though. **Using any other element than the doctype, html, head and body tags will make this work**.

Comment: @Milanzor Hence why you clone the `body` element. It's perfectly fine to have a `div` contain a `body`, so long as they aren't actually in the document. This technique wouldn't work otherwise.

Comment: ah, that's good to hear. Thanks for clarifying that. Unfortunatly I cannot clone the body as its just part of a string and parsing the string to jQuery e.g. $(string); removes the body element.

Comment: Love the intro and the image. Wonderful pedagogy and great explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Given the information just supplied in the comments describing the actual problem you're trying to solve, you don't need to retrieve the `body` tag's attributes at all, and nor should you be using string searching.  Just do:

```
var $newContent = $('<div>' + data + '</div>').children();
$(document.body).empty().append($newContent);
```

i.e. parse the entire data - `$(data)` - then get all child nodes, and put those in your existing `document.body`.

The `<div> + data + </div>` is necessary because `$(html)` requires a single element (and children) and won't accept the standard HTML boilerplate of `<!DOCTYPE ...><html>...</html>`.  It also appears to strip out the `<head>` and `<body>` tags, leaving behind only their children.   In tests I've just made, given

```
var data = '<!doctype html><html><head></head><body><span>Test</span>' +
           '<span>Test 2</span></body></html>'
```

then

```
$('<div>' + data + '</div>').children()
```

gives just the two `<span>` elements, i.e. the desired contents of data's `<body>` tag.

**EDIT** OK - it seems that doesn't *quite* work out as desired because of the stripping of the `<head>` and `<body>` tags, leaving the original contents of the `<head>` in place.

Try this, instead - it's a combination of your original technique, and this one:

```
var $newContent = $(data.substring(data.indexOf('<body')));
$(document.body).empty().append($newContent);
```

Comment: This is a much more sensible solution than mine, +1. It's less fun, though.

Comment: @lonesomeday the problem with your answer is that it addresses the problem the OP _thought_ he had, not the one he actually has ;-)

Comment: That's an interesting reflection on what makes a good programmer: it's not knowing the answers, but knowing the right questions...

Comment: Almost there, the returned data in my ajax request contains a whole html document, including doctype, html tag and the rest. $(data).children() doesn't contain all elements in the body tag. $(data).find('body') didn't work either. $(data).children() works if I put 2 nested <divs> in my <body> (it gets the content in the 2nd div, but that's not the behaviour I want to see

Comment: @Milfert right - that's because `$(data)` only works if `data` is a single node, but you've got two nodes - `doctype` and `html`.

Comment: @Alnitak yeah, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Milfert it looks like my code above will work if you use `$('<div>' + data + '</div>').children()`.

Comment: @Alnitak really appreciating your help. When jQuery parses a string to a jQuery object, it removes the body tag. Check my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neJHN/1 ---- Didn't see your edit. Yeah, it should do that. Check updated fiddle

Comment: @Milfert yes - I found that too - my answer was already updated to show that.

Comment: @Milfert also, don't forget that the point of my answer is _not_ to find the body tag string itself, but to find the _contents_ of it, since that's what you're going to put into your page.

Comment: @Alnitak Yeah, very true, noted. Thanks

Comment: If I console.log $(data), the <body> tag isnt even in the list. Doesn't that mean I will never be able to retrieve its contents, as it's not in the jQuery object? http://jsfiddle.net/neJHN/2

Comment: @Milfert I'm looking into that - trying to find definitive documentation.

Comment: @Alnitak - Did you find anything? I found this explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12808939/2003600 -> "Problem is that jQuery creates a DIV and sets innerHTML and then takes DIV children, but since BODY and HEAD elements are not valid DIV childs, then those are not created by browser."

Comment: @Milfert there's stuff in the jQuery docs (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) that says that the browser itself _may_ remove the `<body>` (and other tags).  That said, do you still have any need to get the actual tag?  I thought the ultimate aim was to just get the body's contents.

Comment: @Alnitak I don't need the tag itself, I need all it's contents. But if that's not possible, I will need the tag to get the contents using substring. I'm one step further though, <body> is not a valid child of <div>, so it doesn't get parsed into it. If I use a non-existing tag, it does parse the contents of <head> and <body> into the jQuery object. Check this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neJHN/3/ -> All that remains is removing the tags that are supposed to be in the <head>

Comment: Ah - I see - the contents of the `<head>` are appearing too...  damn

Comment: @Alnitak your indexOf('<body') method isn't working. It returns the DOCTYPE and the rest of the head.  I guess I won't get a better solution than this: http://jsfiddle.net/neJHN/4/ (fiddle code doesnt run, just to show the code, cant paste it in this comment field)

Comment: @Alnitak as I'm pretty new to posting on SO, is it appropriate to answer my own question, putting a detailed description in and mark that as the answer? I'd love to give you the creds and you helped me ALOT, but it's not the actual answer. Thanks alot still, you showed me that helping out on SO is alot of fun, so will be doing that alot more myself.

Comment: @Milfert sure, go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

```
<body id="mybody" class="someclass">
    blah blah...
</body>
```

To get what you want use this:

As @lonesomeday mentioned not all browsers support outerHTML so you have to use your own implementation of it:

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function() {
    return $("<p>").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
};
```

And then use it to receive what you want:

```
var html = $(document.body).outerHTML(),
    html = html.substr(0, html.indexOf('>')+1);
```

So html variable contains `<body id="mybody" class="someclass">`

Comment: I don't need all the HTML, including the contents of <body>, I just need the body tag as a string

Comment: Remember that not all browsers support `outerHTML`.

Comment: @Milfert actually, you do need all of the HTML, for the next step of your problem (see my answer).  The one bit you _don't_ need is the body tag!

Answer (score 0):

it's better to avoid parsing yourself. you might want to look at **https://unifiedjs.com/** - a lot of plugins to do parsing related work.