# Parse entire HTML document from string into jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a document fetched by a `$.get` call, it's a big bloated HTML document. I need to use jQuery to grab an element from it.

I'm trying this (in coffeescript):

```
$.get url, (data) ->
  title = $(data).find('title').text()
```

This doesn't work. In browser console I've whittled this down to `$(document.documentElement.outerHTML).find('title')` where `document.documentElement.outerHTML` gives a string of the document.

I've tried [jQuery.parseHTML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/), with the same result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason why it does not work is because jQuery expects a DOM node to find the 'title' tags. As you noted, you need to parse the html text first.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808770/parsing-of-html-string-using-jquery) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403600/jquery-not-finding-elements-inside-of-results-from-jquery-parsehtml), the solution is to parse the string and append it into a temporal div (or other element):

```
var tempDom = $('<div></div>').append($.parseHTML(str));
```

Then, you can manipulate `tempDom` to find elements.

**Working demo**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKwLMP

Comment: Worked at first attempt !!!

Answer (score 11):

#### TL;DR ... use the [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) API

```js
var htmlString = "<html><head><title>Name</title></head><body><div class='content'>Hello</div></body></html>";
var htmlDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(htmlString, "text/xml");
```

---

Unfortunately, there current answers don't hit a lot of edge cases

You should ***not*** use `$.parseHTML(htmlString)` as it's immediately lossy.  If we check the source code on [`$.parseHtml`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.2.4/src/core/parseHTML.js#L12), it'll call [`buildFragment`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.2.4/src/manipulation/buildFragment.js#L42) which creates a temporary DOM element and sets the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property.

[image: innerHtml Parsing]

*Element*.`innerHTML` provides an API for:

- [**Parsing** (*string -> DOM*)](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#dfn-parsing) in the write operation
- [**Serializing** (*DOM -> string*)](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#dfn-serializing) in the read operation

And here's the **spec** for [Html Fragment Parsing Algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#html-fragment-parsing-algorithm)

Taking a sample string, here's the result of trying various HTML Parsing approaches:

```js
var htmlString = "<html><head><title>Name</title></head><body><div class='content'>Hello</div></body></html>";

function ParseHtmlTests() {

  /*** $.parseHTML ***/
  var $parseHtml = $.parseHTML(htmlString)

  console.LogOutput(
    '1. $.parseHTML',
    $parseHtml,
    $parseHtml.map(function(el, i) { return el.outerHTML }),
    $($parseHtml).find("title").text(),
    $($parseHtml).find(".content").text()
  )


  /*** tempDiv.innerHTML ***/
  var tempDiv = document.createElement("div")
  tempDiv.innerHTML = htmlString

  console.LogOutput(
    '2. tempDiv.innerHTML',
    tempDiv,
    tempDiv.outerHTML,
    $(tempDiv).find("title").text(),
    $(tempDiv).find(".content").text()
  )


  /*** divAppendContents ***/
  var $divAppendContents = $('<div></div>').append(htmlString)

  console.LogOutput(
    '3. divAppendContents',
    $divAppendContents,
    $divAppendContents.html(),
    $divAppendContents.find("title").text(),
    $divAppendContents.find(".content").text()
  )


  /*** tempHtml.innerHTML ***/
  var tmpHtml = document.createElement( 'html' );
  tmpHtml.innerHTML = htmlString;

  console.LogOutput(
   '4. tempHtml.innerHTML',
    tmpHtml,
    tmpHtml.outerHTML,
    tmpHtml.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerText,
    tmpHtml.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].innerText
  )


  /*** DOMParser.parseFromString ***/
  var htmlDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(htmlString, "text/xml");

  console.LogOutput(
    '5. DOMParser.parseFromString',
    htmlDoc,
    htmlDoc.documentElement.outerHTML,
    htmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML,
    htmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].innerHTML
  )
}

/*** Create Console Log Methods ***/
console.group = console.group || function(msg) {
  console.log(msg)
}
console.groupEnd = console.groupEnd || function(msg) {
  console.log("----------------------------")
}
console.LogOutput = function(method, dom, html, title, content) {
  console.group(method);
  console.log("DOM:", dom)
  console.log("HTML:", html)
  console.log("Title:", title)
  console.log("Content:", content)
  console.groupEnd();
};

/*** Execute Script ***/
ParseHtmlTests()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

And here's the output from the above script in chrome:

[image: Output]

The best approach seems to be creating a HTML Root object by setting the `innerHTML` of a temporary HTML document or by using the [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) API

Further Reading:

- [Parse an HTML string with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10585029/1366033)
- [Parsing of html string using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12808770/1366033)
- [jQuery not finding elements in `jQuery.parseHTML()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15403600/1366033)