# JQuery get/load cannot parse new DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I'm trying to load another page content via AJAX. It loads the content, but I have a problem with parsing new content.

Here is my code

```
  $.get(urlPath, function (content) {
                var newDom = $(content);
                var newTitle = newDom.find("title").text();
                console.log(newDom);
                console.log(newDom.find(CLASS.MAIN_CONTENT));
                console.log(newTitle);
                $(CLASS.MAIN_CONTENT).replaceWith(newDom.find(CLASS.MAIN_CONTENT));
            });
```

And this doesn't work, I get the valid content from request but still cannot get any element from new DOM
Here is output of parsed with `$(content)`

[image]

And here is the raw output of the content `console.log(content)`

[image]

What can be wrong, why this doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

First, note that using `$()` to parse that HTML will throw away some of it because `$()` expects to be parsing *body content*, not a full document. So elements that seem like they should be nested within the structure may end up at the top level of the jQuery object. For instance:

```js
var content = $(
  "<!doctype html>" +
  "<html>" +
  "<head><title>Example</title></head>" +
  "<body>" +
  "<p>Hi there</p>" +
  "</body>" +
  "</html>"
);
console.log(content.length); // 2
content.each(function() {
  console.log(this.tagName); // TITLE, P
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`find` looks *within* the top-level elements in a jQuery object, but doesn't look at the top-level elements themselves, just their descendants. If the element matching your `CLASS.MAIN_CONTENT` selector is at the top level, it won't be found by `find`. You'd want `filter` instead. If it may be in either location, you want a combination of `find` and `filter`:

```
var mainContent = newDom.find(CLASS.MAIN_CONTENT).add(newDom.filter(CLASS.MAIN_CONTENT));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how can I parse new title in this case ? And I need just to add the new block with CLASS.MAIN_CONTENT selector to the existing DOM replacing the old one

Comment: @HelloMufecayo: I don't understand the question. You use the jQuery object you get from `filter` (or `find`, or the combination of the two)...?

Comment: I used this solution it works fine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30676999/parse-entire-html-document-from-string-into-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
 var newDom = $('<div></div>').append($.parseHTML(content));
                document.title = newDom.find("title").text();
                $(CLASS.MAIN_CONTENT).replaceWith(newDom.find(CLASS.MAIN_CONTENT));
```