# Select DOM element from HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML string as follows (defined in javascript):

```
<body>
    <div id="stuff">
    bla bla bla
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    Actual content is here.
    </div>
</body>
```

Above html is my string. I would like to append the div with the id "content" to my actual html file.

How can I read (or parse?) and append a html string like this via jquery?

Comment: from the html string string @MarkC.

Comment: you want to add another div inside your id="content", am i right ?

Comment: @JohnReyM.Baylen no, that whole html you see above is my string. I want to (somehow) parse it and add it's div "content" to another html file

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's parseHTML method:

```js
var htmlString = "<body><div id='stuff'>wahwahwah</div><div id='content'>blahblahblah</div></body>"; //your HTML string here.

var parsedHTML= $.parseHTML(htmlString);

var contentDiv = $(parsedHTML).filter('#content');

$('html').append(contentDiv);
```

Comment: I used the example above.

Comment: The example above won't work since I didn't include a valid HTML string. I'll update with a real example in the next minute.

Comment: OK, try what I have now.

Comment: I realized that removing the .parseHTML still makes it work

Comment: I mean directly using $(htmlString)

Comment: si there any specificreason you use parse first?

Comment: No, you can just do it directly.

Comment: I'm unable to load it properly

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808770/parsing-of-html-string-using-jquery

Comment: I don't want to add the html to my dom though @tagraves

Comment: What's the problem with your example then?

Comment: as you see it's not working properly, check the background-color part