# Jquery : Find elements inside HEAD tag from a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Wondering how can i find the 'link' element inside the HEAD tag from variable 'x' using Jquery?

Tried, but below code is not working.

```
var x = "<html><head> <link> I'm inside head tag </link> </head></html>";

var y = $('<div>' + x + '</div>');

y.find('head')[0].html();

alert(y);
```

Comment: why put a html inside a div?

Comment: Actually i want to find the LINK element inside the HEAD tag and  replace the inner content and return the entire html.

Comment: I believe jQuery is stripping out the `<html>` and `<head>` tags. The innerHTML of the `<div>` is `" <link> I'm inside head tag  "` using jQuery version 2.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property since index `0` returns DOM object or directly apply [`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) method on jQuery object.

Although you can't directly parse the HTML string which contains [`HEAD` or `BODY`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12808939/3037257) tags(which would avoid those elements since it can't be a child of a div element) so you need to treat it as XML.  To parse XML use [`$.parseXML()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/) the result would be an array of nodes, now converts into jQuery object by simply wrapping using jQuery and do the rest.

```js
var x = "<html><head> <link> I'm inside head tag </link> </head><body></body></html>";

// parse the string as XML and generate XML document
// and wrap using jQuery to generate jQuery object from it
var y = $($.parseXML(x));

// get DOM object by index and get html content
var a = y.find('head')[0].innerHTML;
// or use jQuery method to get content
var b = y.find('head').html();

console.log(a, b)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Refer : [Parsing of html string using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808770/parsing-of-html-string-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find the link(s) from the document header, you can use this selector

```
$('head link')
```

However, if you need to find the link element(s) inside the header from a variable, you can do this

```
var x = "<html><head> <link> I'm inside head tag </link> </head></html>";
$(x).filter( function (i,a){ return $(a).is('link');});
```